# Post html form from asp mvc controller to another website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, controller

I need to post a form to a credit card processor webpage where the user insert the credit card data.

I actually post the form to the credit card processor webpage from the view and it works fine, but I want to hide some parameters that I have to send in the form to the credit card processor so it knows where the money goes. if the user see the source code of the payment page he will see the parameters.

I am thinking in post the form from the controller and add the parameters here before posting.

If I find the way to post from the controller, will it show the credit card processor webpage when posted?

Comment: Is the credit card processor webpage a third party site, or is it your own?

Comment: It is a third party site.

Comment: Are you using a `https` connection to post to the third party site? If not, then I would research about setting up a `https` connection.

Comment: The third party site use ssl. but I want to hide the parameters from my site user, so it does not matter if I use https because once he is in the page, the page is unencripted and he can use a right click and select "show source".   Edit: it is not a transport problem.

Comment: Your credit card gateway should provide you with an api that you can call.

Comment: That is another approach with the problem that I have to handle the credit card data. Using the credit card processor webpage all responsibility for credit card fraud relay on them and not in me because the only things my website see about the credit card are the last 4 digits, the transaction Id and the approval number